# How to use $lookup in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have two collections:
Races and Racers
I want to aggregate the two collections.

I want two join both collections and calculate the average speed two teams.

I know that I need to use $lookup and then `$group`.

One problem that I get always NULL after using `$lookup`.

I use this code:

```
db.getCollection(‘Racers’).aggregate([
    {$lookup:{
        from:“Races”,
        localField:“last_name”,
        foreignField:“last_name”,
        as:“Time”
    }}
])
```

Can anyone explain me the problem and how I should solve it? Thank you in advance!

Collections screenshoots:

- https://ibb.co/KVM69y6
- https://ibb.co/MgFv8MD

and results that i get:
https://ibb.co/k0Hfysy

I provide collections that I use (I insert all value in one insert):

```
 db.getCollection('Racers').insert(
                       {_id:"PP12",first_name:"Peter",last_name: "Pet",Number:12, Team:{Name:"Gowl",Colour:"Red",Number:"1"}},
                       {_id:"GG22",first_name:"George",last_name: "Ge",Number:22, Team:{Name:"Gowl",Colour:"Green",Number:"2"}},
                      {_id:"JJ15",first_name:"John",last_name: "Jo",Number:15, Team:{Name:"Lion",Colour:"Orange",Number:"1"}},
                      {_id:"UU27",first_name:"Uther",last_name: "Ut",Number:27, Team:{Name:"Lion",Colour:"White",Number:"2"}}
                       )

db.getCollection('Races').insert(
                       {_id:"PP12",last_name: "Pet",Osaka_Time:350},
                       {_id:"GG22",last_name: "Ge",Osaka_Time:355},
                      {_id:"JJ15",last_name: "Jo",Osaka_Time:356},
                      {_id:"UU27",last_name: "Ut",Osaka_Time:351}
                       )
```

Comment: Please provide races collection data also

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: I provided both collections that I use.